# Is this bad to add two inject methods inside an unless in ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I wrote a simple ruby code(actually in sinatra), and I used to write two inject methods inside an unless case. I really like to know is there any error or is this a bad habit to write like this.

```
unless @profile_ids.empty?
  matching_users_counts = Profile.find(:all, :conditions => "id in (#{@profile_ids.join(',')})").collect { |pro| pro.matching_users_count.to_i }
  total_dnd_counts = Job.find(:all, :conditions => "rundate = '#{date}'").collect { |job| job.count_after_dnd.to_i }
  @profles_count = matching_users_counts.inject(0, &:+)
  @dnd_count = total_dnd_counts.inject(0, &:+)

  @sum = @profiles_counts - @dnd_counts
#@sum -= count
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular problem in putting injects inside an unless block, you can add whatever you want. But this code in particular:

1. Should have `end` to close your unless conditional
2. Your `find` calls are too long, you should always try to keep short lines for readability. [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) recommends limiting lines to 80 characters. So split up `find` and `collect` into separate lines.

Comment: If that helped you out, consider upvoting or marking as solution. Would help out a lot

Answer (score 0):

As Maxim said, no particular problem in putting injects inside unless block. If I should criticize your code, I'd personally do what you did in collect and inject methods in the queries you do at the beginning of the unless block, SQL provide tools to make all that computation in one query.

Comment: will you olease tell me these tools make it simpler

Comment: I can't teach you SQL in one comment. But give a look at GROUP BY and SUM.